# Help with my first Service

Tags: android, android-service

I want to add some functionality to my Android device.
However i don't want to know it is there. I want it to run in the background entirely,
 and i want it to run all the time(as long as my phone is On).

If simplifying what i want to do:
I want my device to have a file "FileName.txt" which will be identical to "FileName.txt" on my FTP server.
I want to make an application that will connect to my FTP server every 1 minute and validates that the time-stamp of the local file is identical to the time-stamp of the remote file.
Hence if i open a notepad op the server and edit this file, than open my local file
with some program on the device the content will be identical.
I already know how to connect to the FTP server and how to download the file, the question is in what context will i do this...?

This was a very simplifying idea of what i want to make...

However i read the Service class description and it is said that my Service program will ran as long as the Intent that activate her is operational....

How can i make a real service like application? i don't want any application to be running all the time.

What should i do guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want it to run in the background entirely, and i want it to run all the time(as long as my phone is On).

Please do not do this.

> I want to make an application that will connect to my FTP server every 1 minute and validates that the time-stamp of the local file is identical to the time-stamp of the remote file.

I do not recommend a polling period of one minute (make it longer), but otherwise this is a fine use case for `AlarmManager` and an `IntentService`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, the time period of 1 minute was an arbitrary value. why shouldn't i make an application run in the background all the time? is there any other suggested solution?
Anyway the IntentService seems to be a class which should 
"the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work. "
How can this help me? I have heared the broadcast recivers, do you know this?

Comment: @talel: " why shouldn't i make an application run in the background all the time?" -- first, it won't work. Second, you waste RAM. Third, users will hate you for wasting RAM and will attack your application with task killers or will give you poor ratings on the Market. "How can this help me?" -- because that is precisely how you should be implementing something that checks a server periodically.